# How to make the flex children of a parent that is itself a flex child have as max height the height of the parent determined by its own flex status?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say you have a div with display flex, flex-direction column, say with height 600 for this example.

It has three children, each with property flex equal to 1. The first two children render some simple text, the third one renders an h1 and a list of strings, and it has display flex column as well. These strings come from an array of string.

Let's say that we have an additional button (not important) that when we click it it adds an element to the array of string. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-night-691vr) is the codesandbox for the description just given. This is a general JS question, but the example is in a very simple React component.

Initially, all three children have the same size (200), because they all have flex 1. However, after a few clicks on the button, the list in the third child becomes bigger than the available space in the third child, and the third child starts to expand and the other two children to shrink. **How can one make the list contained in the third child have at most the space allocated to it initially and after that to just have overflow scroll?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the `overscrollY: "scroll"` on that div.

[Your updated fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-einstein-5brqi)

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with setting min-heights, in your example, you would set `min-height:200px` for each block.  Then, as the bottom block flexes the two top blocks would never go less than 200px.  The final step to make it work in your example would be to set `overflow-y:scroll` for your third block.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-worker-f56zn

Answer (score 1):

Try to set maxHeight to 85px for example and overflowY to scroll

```
<ul style={{ flex: 1, maxHeight: "85px", overflowY: "scroll" }}>
            {list.map((el, i) => (
              <li key={i}>el</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
```